# Skip first x rows when setting a column value in a DataFrame with a non-integer index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Lets say I want to set a columns value in a `DataFrame`.

1. It works when I do have standard integer indexes:

```
df.loc[14:, 'avg_gain'] = 5
```

but when I have a `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df.set_index(keys=['ts'], inplace=True)
```

(or another Index, which is non-integer), it yields

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [14] of <class 'int'>
)
```

So how is it possible to skip the first `x`rows when applying new values on a `DataFrame` which has an alternative index than the standard one?

Comment: Love it.. Works! Just make sure that the column `avg_gain` is already in the `df`. Otherwise `get_loc` can not find it. Would you like to copy it to an answer @Erfan? Otherwise I will summarize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) which is position based indexing. [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) is label based indexing, so it does not recognize `14:` if your index is datetime:

```
df.iloc[14:, df.columns.get_loc('avg_gain')] = 5
```

Or with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df.index[14:], 'avg_gain'] = 5
```

---

Note: [`Index.get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) will throw an error if the column does not exist, so make sure the column exists.

Comment: With `.loc`: `np.arange(len(df)) >= 14` for the rows will be safer in case of duplicated indices.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the .loc[] property is primarily label based. That means that the 14: you have entered grabs the rows from index 14 as a string and not as an integer. If you set the index on a column which contains strings you have to adjust it accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                   'B': ['a','b','c','d','e','f']})

    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   4   d
4   5   e
5   6   f
```

Then you can use .loc

```
df.loc[:1]

    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   b
```

Set the index on a column with strings

```
df = df.set_index('B')
    A
B   
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
e   5
f   6

df.loc[:'b']

    A
B   
a   1
b   2
```

You can also use the .iloc property which is primarily integer position based:

```
df.iloc[:2,:]
    A
B   
a   1
b   2
```